# Windows 10 IoT embedded, trying to get a console app debugging/deployed using Visual Stuido 2019

Tags: c++, embedded, visual-studio-2019, iot

I've been trying to get a 'console application' to deploy and debug on my embedded Win10 device but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I can get an application to deploy, which requires a 'SquareLogo' screen to come up and I can't figure how to have this 'window' hide or be a headless app.

I can set in the property pages of my app "Property Pages - Configuration Properties - Linker - System - SubSystem" to 'Console (SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) and the console window will display on the embedded device but the app screen comes up and the console window will not take any input, from the keyboard.

So in summation I want to debug (Remote Machine) to my embedded Win10 device with a console application.

I'm writing my app in C++.

I won't think it would be this hard but I just can't get the applications main window to not display at startup.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: May i know the Windows 10 IoT Embedded that you were talking about is Windows IoT Core?

Comment: Yes one could use that

Answer (score 0):

For Windows IoT Core, you can debug console app using Remote Console App Debugging in Visual Studio. You need to start visual studio debugger on Windows IoT Core in Device Portal.
Please refer to this document.

[Debug your app using Remote Console App Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/remotedebugging)

BTW, IoT Core is a UWP centric OS and UWP apps are its primary app type.Since that , traditional UI app can not work on Windows IoT Core, it means Windows IoT Core does not support MFC or ATL APIs.If you want to run a headless app on Windows IoT Core, we recommend you to use [Background Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications).